# Handling Body class based on Template

Tags: php, functions, filters, hooks, body-class

Through a **PHP function**, I think I can handle body class, but I think **WordPress** would have some specific way to handle it.

If `Home.php` then class in the body should be `wbody` else it should be `bgody`.

As I said I can write **PHP functions** to print class based on the template, but Is there a more precise way to do this in the case of **WordPress**?

Comment: please try this code : add_filter( 'body_class','halfhalf_body_class' );
function halfhalf_body_class( $classes ) {
 
    if ( is_page_template( 'page-halfhalf.php' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'halfhalf-page';
    }
     
    return $classes;
     
}

Comment: please check url : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/adding-to-the-body-class-in-wordpress--cms-21077

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but...

If you want to set body classes based on current page, then you can use this code

```
function my_body_class( $classes ) {
    if ( is_home() ) {
        $classes[] = 'wbody';
    } else {
        $classes[] = 'gbody';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_body_class' );
```

Of course you can use other conditions in there and the list of [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) might come in handy to.

Comment: If here we want to add one more template → 'if ( is_home() ||  )' After the or symbol how should we target the other page template such as page-docs.php?

Comment: You can use `is_page_template()` then (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/).